# p5.Image from get() is drawn blurry due to pixelDensity issue p5js

Tags: p5.js

I'm using `get()` to store a snapshot of each state in my animation, and then replaying those later using `image`.

When I render the stored pixels with `image` however, they do not appear to have the same pixel density of the original image, which causes the image to be rendered fuzzy. I can "fix" this by setting `pixelDensity(1)` in the setup function but this just causes the whole animation to be fuzzy on my screen.

Here's a working example. Hopefully you can see how the text becomes blurry when moving to the left (i.e. when being rendered with `image`)
https://editor.p5js.org/toc/sketches/63CYsMrH3

[Clear animation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVbVj.png)
[Fuzzy animation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27drl.png)

```js
let L = 400
let history, iter, x

function init() {
  history = []
  iter = 0
  x = 0
}

function writeText() {
  textSize(25)
  textFont("Courier New")
  fill(0)
  text("fuzzy wuzzy", x, L/2)
  textSize(15)
  text("why though???", x, L/3)
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(L, L)
  // pixelDensity(1)
  frameRate(60)
  init()
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  iter += 1
  
  if (iter < 100) {
    x += L/700
    writeText()
    
    let im = get()
    history.push(im) 
  }
  else {
    if (history.length === 0) {
      init()
    } else {
      im = history.pop()
      image(im, 0, 0, L, L)  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that this has to do with saving space or that when p5js draws any objects it's not part of the screen but separate and get() just combines everything. I brought it across thinking it might be the web editor's fault but no luck, and increasing or decreasing the pixel density makes it more fuzzy-wuzzy for lagy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p5.Image` class doesn't have any concept of pixel density, so while the canvas itself is packing 4 pixels into each pixel coordinate, the image returned by `get()` just has 1 pixel for each pixel coordinate which is the average of those four. The simplest way to solve this would be to create a new image with `createImage()` and give it dimensions accounting for the `pixelDensity()` of your sketch, and then use the `copy()` function to save the canvas pixels  to the image.

```js
const L = 400;
let history, iter, x;

function init() {
  history = [];
  iter = 0;
  x = 0;
}

function writeText() {
  textSize(25);
  textFont("Courier New");
  fill(0);
  text("fuzzy wuzzy", x, L / 2);
  textSize(15);
  text("why though???", x, L / 3);
}

let cnvs;
let density;

function setup() {
  cnvs = createCanvas(L, L);
  density = pixelDensity();
  console.log(`density: ${density}`);
  frameRate(60);
  init();
}

function draw() {
  iter += 1;

  if (iter < 100) {
    background(220);
    x += L / 700;
    writeText();

    let im = createImage(width * density, height * density);
    im.copy(cnvs, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width * density, height * density);
    history.push(im);
  } else if (history.length === 0) {
    init();
  } else {
    im = history.pop();
    image(im, 0, 0, L, L);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you very much.